# Recommended array indexing

Tags: coding-style

A classmate of mine suggested that, we should start indexing arrays from 1 and not from zero, because, we declare lots of unnecessary variables in our code and starting with 1 is more natural. But, I always used the 0th index of an array so far although if I left the 0th index unused and started from 1st index I think it will be more convenient for me.
Which is the recommended approach?

Answer (score 0):

It is not even a problem. If you are using 0 as your starting index then you have to use i-1 to reference your indexes instead of writing direct i. Using 1 as a first index will make 1 integer space go waste. So, i would recommend you to start with index 0 only.

Comment: but hey, i am aware that an integer will be unused. but don't we all  use variables in our code that could be avoided?

Comment: you will hae to use equal number of variables only. refer your array by i-1th index instead of ith